# Is there an error in this proof showing dual functor over free module is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, modules, solution-verification

**How is $g(\mu(m))= f(m)$ when $\mu(m)=n-\rho(\nu(n))$?**

---

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: What is supposed to not be right?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout My question is the very first line of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $\mu(m) - \rho(\nu(\mu(m))) = \mu(m) - \rho(0) = \mu(m)$ by exactness of the first sequence $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow P \rightarrow 0$.

Edit: To show that $g(\rho(\nu(n)) = 0$, note that $g(n) = f(m)$, with $m$ the unique element of $M$ such that $\mu(m) = n - \rho(\nu(n))$. So $\rho(\nu(n)) - \rho(\nu(n)) = 0 = \mu(0)$. Hence $g(\rho(\nu(n)) = f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Not sure how this answers why $g(\rho(\nu(n)))=0$.

Comment: See the edit, hopefully it is clear